# Detect Client's Local IP address

Tags: sql-server-2008, ip, local

My question is is that possible to detect the current connected client's local IP address (somethings like 192.168.1... not the WAN IP)

I'm aware of `sys.dm_exec_connections` but never had the chance to test it since I don't possess more than 1 computer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Provided query returns IP address of current client connection.

```
select max(client_net_address) client_net_address
from sys.dm_exec_connections
where session_id=@@SPID
```